# Xcode Swift 7.3 Playing Audio File

Tags: xcode, swift, audio, swift2

I get an error when trying to play an audio file. The error I get is below.

> sender    UIButton    0x00007f86b2615bf0
>   self  PlayAudio.ViewController    0x00007f86b261cca0

image of error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlgyi.png)

[image]
Any suggestions?
RonneRock

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to catch the error:

```
do{
    audioPlayer.play()
}catch {
    print("Error getting the audio file")
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yup sure there are suggestions , delete the Action and create it again while creating be sure the sender is UIButton  ,you have  AnyObject as Sender.and yes do try that do catch

Comment: I have deleted the Action and recreated it again with the sender as "UIButton". No luck. Same error. All I want to do is run  a simple test to play an audio file.

Comment: Have you tried ,  do catch .          do{
    audioPlayer.play()
}catch {
    print("Error getting the audio file")
}                  and try writing  Apple.mp3  in name and ofType = nil

Comment: Follow this simple tutorial at              https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-play-sounds-using-avaudioplayer